# Google Cloud Speech infinite streaming recognize in Go does not receive results after restarting the stream

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech

I am trying to implement the equivalent of the `InfiniteStreamingRecognize` example in Go. This exercise has been implemented in Java, Python and Node.js according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/endless-streaming-tutorial).

During the first run transcription results are being received fine (with interim results option enabled). Unfortunately, after restarting the stream, no results are received. The new stream instance is configured the same way as the first, I also tried creating a new client from scratch without luck.

Specifically I make sure I wait for the stream to close after calling `CloseSend()` on it. After that, using the newly created stream I send a new initial message with configuration. If there is any unfinished audio data I send that too before sending any new audio data from my buffer. But my receiver routine stays blocks at `stream.Recv()` waiting for a response.

Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Here is my code (implemented as an `echo` (web framework) handler listening to web socket connections:

```
package handlers

import (
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
    "time"

    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
    echo "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"

    speech "cloud.google.com/go/speech/apiv1"
    speechpb "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/speech/v1"
)

const MAX_STREAM_DURATION = 60000 // seconds

func SpeechToText(c echo.Context) error {
    var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{CheckOrigin: func(r *http.Request) bool { return true }}

    ws, err := upgrader.Upgrade(c.Response(), c.Request(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer ws.Close()

    var speechSamplesBuf bytes.Buffer
    startTime := time.Now()
    restart := make(chan bool)

    go recognizeManager(restart, &speechSamplesBuf)

    for {
        duration := time.Since(startTime)

        if duration.Milliseconds() > MAX_STREAM_DURATION {
            fmt.Println("M - Duration reached")
            startTime = time.Now()
            restart <- true
            fmt.Println("M - Notified restart channel")
        }

        _, msg, err := ws.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            c.Logger().Error(err)
        }

        n, _ := speechSamplesBuf.Write(msg)
        fmt.Printf("M - Read: %d Total: %d\n", n, speechSamplesBuf.Len())
    }
}

func createNewClients(cfg speechpb.RecognitionConfig) (*speech.Client, *speechpb.Speech_StreamingRecognizeClient, error) {
    ctx := context.Background()
    return createNewClientsWithContext(ctx, cfg)
}

func createNewClientsWithContext(ctx context.Context, cfg speechpb.RecognitionConfig) (*speech.Client, *speechpb.Speech_StreamingRecognizeClient, error) {
    fmt.Println("RM - Creating new clients")
    fmt.Printf("RM - Sleeping for 1 second.. ")
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    fmt.Printf("OK\n")

    client, err := speech.NewClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    stream, err := client.StreamingRecognize(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err := stream.Send(&speechpb.StreamingRecognizeRequest{
        StreamingRequest: &speechpb.StreamingRecognizeRequest_StreamingConfig{
            StreamingConfig: &speechpb.StreamingRecognitionConfig{
                Config:         &cfg,
                InterimResults: true,
            },
        },
    }); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return client, &stream, nil
}

func createNewStream(cfg speechpb.RecognitionConfig, c *speech.Client) (*speechpb.Speech_StreamingRecognizeClient, error) {
    ctx := context.Background()
    return createNewStreamWithContext(ctx, cfg, c)
}

func createNewStreamWithContext(ctx context.Context, cfg speechpb.RecognitionConfig, c *speech.Client) (*speechpb.Speech_StreamingRecognizeClient, error) {
    fmt.Println("RM - Creating new stream")
    fmt.Printf("RM - Sleeping for 1 second.. ")
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    fmt.Printf("OK\n")

    stream, err := c.StreamingRecognize(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err := stream.Send(&speechpb.StreamingRecognizeRequest{
        StreamingRequest: &speechpb.StreamingRecognizeRequest_StreamingConfig{
            StreamingConfig: &speechpb.StreamingRecognitionConfig{
                Config:         &cfg,
                InterimResults: true,
            },
        },
    }); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return &stream, nil
}

func recognizeManager(restart <-chan bool, buf *bytes.Buffer) {
    chs := 2

    //restart channels for go routines
    var rcs []chan bool
    // for i := 0; i < chs; i++ {
    //  rcs[i] = make(chan bool)
    // }
    fmt.Println("RM - Declared restart channels for go routines")

    cfg := speechpb.RecognitionConfig{
        Encoding:        speechpb.RecognitionConfig_WEBM_OPUS,
        SampleRateHertz: 48000,
        LanguageCode:    "el-GR"}

    // ctx := context.Background()

    var client *speech.Client
    var stream *speechpb.Speech_StreamingRecognizeClient
    var err error

    ctx := context.Background()
    client, err = speech.NewClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    lastAudioSentBuf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    audioSentBuf := new(bytes.Buffer)

    finalRequestEndTime := new(int64) // in ms
    //var bridgingOffset int64      // in ms
    var bytesFromMs int

    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
    started := false
    for {
        // fmt.Printf("B%d ", buf.Len())
        select {
        case <-restart:
            fmt.Println("RM - Restart message received")
            for i := 0; i < len(rcs); i++ {
                rcs[i] <- true
            }

            wg.Wait()

            fmt.Println("RM - Go routines have finished")
            fmt.Println("RM - finalRequestEndTime:", finalRequestEndTime)
            fmt.Println("RM - *finalRequestEndTime:", *finalRequestEndTime)
            // err := stream.CloseSend()
            // if err != nil {
            //  log.Fatal(err)
            // }

            rate := audioSentBuf.Len() / MAX_STREAM_DURATION
            lastAudioSentBuf.Write(audioSentBuf.Bytes())
            audioSentBuf.Reset()

            finalOffsetInWindow := *finalRequestEndTime % MAX_STREAM_DURATION
            fmt.Printf("finalOffsetInWindow = %v MOD %v = %v\n", *finalRequestEndTime, MAX_STREAM_DURATION, finalOffsetInWindow)

            bytesFromMs = rate * int(finalOffsetInWindow)
            fmt.Println("bytesFromMs:", bytesFromMs)

            // fmt.Println("RM - Stream was closed")
            finalRequestEndTime = new(int64)

            started = false
        default:
            if started {
                // fmt.Println("RM - Already started, sleeping 2 secs")
                continue
            }

            fmt.Println("RM - Not started, need to start right now")
            // if client != nil {
            //  client.Close()
            // }
            if stream != nil {
                (*stream).CloseSend()
            }
            stream, err = createNewStream(cfg, client)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }

            //restart channels for go routines
            rcs = make([]chan bool, chs)
            for i := 0; i < chs; i++ {
                rcs[i] = make(chan bool)
            }

            wg = new(sync.WaitGroup)
            // sender
            wg.Add(1)
            go startSend(rcs[0], buf, audioSentBuf, lastAudioSentBuf, bytesFromMs, stream, wg)
            // receiver
            wg.Add(1)
            go startReceive(rcs[1], finalRequestEndTime, stream, wg)
            fmt.Println("RM - Started bootstrap go routine (start)")
            started = true
        }
    }
}

func startSend(rc chan bool, messages *bytes.Buffer, audioSentBuf *bytes.Buffer, lastAudioSentBuf *bytes.Buffer, bytesFromMs int, stream *speechpb.Speech_StreamingRecognizeClient, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    fmt.Println("S - Start")
    fmt.Println("S - Using stream:", stream)
    // fmt.Printf("%s [send] go() \n", mytime())
    // begin := false
    buf := make([]byte, 1024)

    if lastAudioSentBuf.Len() > 0 {
        var b bytes.Buffer
        b.Write(lastAudioSentBuf.Bytes()[bytesFromMs:])
        lastAudioSentBuf.Reset()
        fmt.Printf("S - Resending %db \n", b.Len())
    loop:
        for {
            n, err := b.Read(buf)
            if n > 0 {
                fmt.Printf("S - Resending %db (partial)\n", len(buf[:n]))
                if err := (*stream).Send(&speechpb.StreamingRecognizeRequest{
                    StreamingRequest: &speechpb.StreamingRecognizeRequest_AudioContent{
                        AudioContent: buf[:n],
                    },
                }); err != nil {
                    log.Printf("Could not resend audio: %v", err)
                } else {
                }
            }
            if err == io.EOF {
                // Nothing else to pipe, move on to new audio.
                break loop
                // Nothing else to pipe
            }
            if err != nil {
                log.Printf("Could not read from messages buffer: %v", err)
                break loop
            }
        }
    }

    for {
        select {
        case <-rc:
            // fmt.Printf("%s [send] go() - return \n", mytime())
            if err := (*stream).CloseSend(); err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("Could not close stream: %v", err)
            }
            fmt.Println("S - Stopping")
            return
        default:
            // fmt.Println("S - Continue")
            // // fmt.Printf("%s [send] continue \n", mytime())
        }

        if messages.Len() == 0 {
            // fmt.Printf("0")
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
            continue
        }

        n, err := messages.Read(buf)
        // // fmt.Printf("%s [send] (reading %db / %db) \n", mytime(), n, messages.Len())
        // fmt.Println("sending stream:", &stream)
        if n > 0 {
            // t = &newT
            // fmt.Printf("%s [send] sending %db \n", mytime(), len(buf[:n]))
            fmt.Printf("S - Sending %db \n", len(buf[:n]))
            if err := (*stream).Send(&speechpb.StreamingRecognizeRequest{
                StreamingRequest: &speechpb.StreamingRecognizeRequest_AudioContent{
                    AudioContent: buf[:n],
                },
            }); err != nil {
                log.Printf("Could not send audio: %v", err)
            } else {
                fmt.Printf("S - Sent %db (to %v)\n", len(buf[:n]), stream)
                audioSentBuf.Write(buf)
                fmt.Printf("S - Total Audio Sent %db \n", audioSentBuf.Len())
                // fmt.Printf("S - Sent %db \n", len(buf[:n]))
                // if !begin {
                //  begin = true
                //  wg.Add(1)
                //  // fmt.Printf("%s [send] starting receiver\n", mytime())
                //  go startReceive(rc[1], stream, wg)
                // }
                // fmt.Printf("%s [send] sent %db \n", mytime(), len(buf[:n]))
            }
        }
        if err == io.EOF {
            // Nothing else to pipe, close the stream.
            if err := (*stream).CloseSend(); err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("Could not close stream: %v", err)
            }
            return
            // Nothing else to pipe
            // fmt.Printf("%s [send] nothing else to pipe \n", mytime())
            // continue
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Could not read from messages buffer: %v", err)
            continue
        }
    }
}

func startReceive(rc <-chan bool, fret *int64, stream *speechpb.Speech_StreamingRecognizeClient, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    var finalRequestEndTime int64
    defer wg.Done()
    fmt.Println("R - Start")
    fmt.Println("R - Using stream:", stream)
    // fmt.Printf("%s [receive] go() \n", mytime())
    for {
        select {
        case <-rc:
            fmt.Println("R - Stopping")
            *fret = finalRequestEndTime
            fmt.Println("R - &fret:", fret)
            // fmt.Printf("%s [receive] go() - return \n", mytime())
            return
        default:
            // fmt.Println("R - Continue")
            // fmt.Printf("%s [receive] continue \n", mytime())
        }

        // fmt.Printf("%s [receive] receiving..\n", mytime())
        // fmt.Println("receiving stream:", &stream)
        fmt.Println("R - Waiting to receive...")
        resp, err := (*stream).Recv()
        fmt.Printf("R - Received (from %v)\n", stream)
        if err == io.EOF {
            fmt.Printf("e\n")
            // // fmt.Printf("%s [receive]: breaking loop\n", mytime())
            // break
            continue
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Cannot stream results: %v", err)
        }
        if err := resp.Error; err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Could not recognize: %v", err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("R - Received %d results\n", len(resp.Results))
        for _, result := range resp.Results {
            if result.IsFinal {
                finalRequestEndTime = result.ResultEndTime.AsDuration().Milliseconds()
                fmt.Println("R - finalRequestEndtime:", finalRequestEndTime)
                fmt.Println("R - fret:", fret)
            }
            fmt.Printf("Result: %+v\n", result)
            // textBuf.Read([]byte(result.Alternatives[0].Transcript))
            // textBuf.Read([]byte(" "))
        }
    }
}
func mytime() string {
    return time.Now().Format("15:04:05")
}
```

Thanks again in advance